# trigger with increment

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm studying triggers and I have trouble running one with a very simple increment.
The triggers runs okay ( no error at execution, but what I meant to do with it is not the result it gives)
This is my trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER results_au AFTER UPDATE 
ON results
FOR EACH ROW
IF new.LocalResult > new.ResultadoVisitant THEN
UPDATE teams
SET wongames = (wongames + 1)
WHERE teams = results.Local;
END IF;
```

The situation is: Two tables, one with all football teams on it, and other with the football scoring.

What I meant to do here is that when I insert a score between two football teams, if Local team wins, the 
teams table gets update with a +1 value to the Local team.

Am I doing the X = X + 1 wrong or am I missing something else? If you need more information, I'll post it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be referring to `new` in the `where` clause:

```
UPDATE teams
    SET wongames = (wongames + 1)
    WHERE equips = new.Local;
-------------------^
```

Comment: Tried that before, didn't work (so it must be another thing added to that solution). I'm working on it. PD: Updated equips for teams (I malfunctioned there)

Comment: Also tried using: WHERE teamname = new.Local (so if the local team that I write wins, it adds a +1 to their win history; sadly does not add anything.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that using AFTER UPDATE is wrong, I have to use AFTER INSERT and then it works, thanks for your help!